# Solr's datetime field is stored wrong

Tags: datetime, solr, format

Why when I try to store the datetime 000-00-00T00:00:00Z (the data source is Mysql) into solr it's saved as 0002-11-30T00:00:00Z?

Can Solr store datetime with format 0000-00-00T00:00:00Z?

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">2</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="334" start="0">
<doc>
  <short name="contacts">0</short>
  <str name="country">PT</str>
  <str name="email"/>
  <date name="first_visit_datetime">0002-11-30T00:00:00Z</date>
  <long name="id">101</long>
  <date name="last_visit_datetime">0002-11-30T00:00:00Z</date>
  <str name="name"/>
  <str name="organization"/>
  <str name="phone"/>
  <str name="region">14</str>
  <short name="visits">0</short>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it's derived from [ISO 8601](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html) and I think it's always the same.

Comment: Ok the response is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime). Thanks @Vincenzo Maggio for the clue :)